# How to refund in paypal? laravel

Tags: laravel-5

If your refund status is Refunded or Partially Refunded, it means that the refund is complete. The money should be back in your PayPal balance or on your credit card

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Third party products might not be supported on Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

please refer your payment method and step by step follow